# How to set null object in properties file groovy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, groovy

I am trying to set a object value to null in properties file but it is always being returned as string. Here is the sample code along with the properties file.

```
File propertiesFile = new File('/opt/config.properties')
propertiesFile.withInputStream {
    properties.load(it)
}

    **config.properties**
    spotConfig = null

println properties.spotConfig
```

But when I am trying to print the above value, it is always returning string whereas I want it to print a null object. How can I do that in groovy? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of explicitly assigning `null` in a properties file. The closest you can get is an empty string as you can read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)).

```
spotConfig
```

Or you can simply not specify the key at all.

Answer (score 1):

`Properties` keys and values are strings. So you can't get a `null` as value from a `Properties` instance containing that key.

In both of these cases, the value will be returned as a string:

```
x=
y=null
```

`properties.get("x")` will return `""`, and `properties.get("y")` will return `"null"` (the literal string).

What you have to do is propbably **remove the key from the file** altogether (don't add a `spotConfig` key in the file) to get `null`